# No recompile of JSX file when debugging

Tags: reactjs.net

ReactJS.NET is not recompiling when debugging.

It compiles once, and then it remains static.

Strangely, when I make an error in my and my app is already built, I can fix the JSX and it will compile without having to rebuild my app but it will only do that once.

Where should I be looking to fix it?

My Web.config has

```
<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="GET" path="*.jsx" type="React.Web.JsxHandlerFactory, React.Web" />
</stem.web
<system.webServer>
      <remove name="Babel" />
      <add name="Babel" verb="GET" path="*.jsx" type="React.Web.BabelHandlerFactory, React.Web" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

and I've call the JSX in my view with all three methods

```
<script src="..."></scripts>
@Scripts.Render("...")
@Url.Content("...")
```

What should I be doing to fix this?

Comment: This sounds like a bug... Could you please report it on the ReactJS.NET Github project?

Comment: Daniel, added it as a Github issue! I'm going to need help giving you more info, but I'm sure we can sort this out :)